# Writing zipfile in Python 3.6 without absolute path

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I am trying to write a zip file using Python's `zipfile` module that starts at a certain subfolder but still maintains the tree structure from that subfolder. For example, if I pass "C:\Users\User1\OneDrive\Documents", the zip file will contain everything from Documents onward, with all of Documents' subfolders maintained within Documents. I have the following code:

```
import zipfile
import os
import datetime

def backup(src, dest):
    """Backup files from src to dest."""
    base = os.path.basename(src)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    newFile = f'{base}_{now.month}-{now.day}-{now.year}.zip'

    # Set the current working directory.
    os.chdir(dest)

    if os.path.exists(newFile):
        os.unlink(newFile)
        newFile = f'{base}_{now.month}-{now.day}-{now.year}_OVERWRITE.zip'

    # Write the zipfile and walk the source directory tree.
    with zipfile.ZipFile(newFile, 'w') as zip:
        for folder, _ , files in os.walk(src):
            print(f'Working in folder {os.path.basename(folder)}')

            for file in files:
                zip.write(os.path.join(folder, file),
                          arcname=os.path.join(
                              folder[len(os.path.dirname(folder)) + 1:], file),
                          compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        print(f'\n---------- Backup of {base} to {dest} successful! ----------\n')
```

I know I have to use the `arcname` parameter for zipfile.write(), but I can't figure out how to get it to maintain the tree structure of the original directory. The code as it is now writes every subfolder to the first level of the zip file, if that makes sense. I've read several posts suggesting I use os.path.relname() to chop off the root, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it properly. I am also aware that this post looks similar to others on Stack Overflow. I have read those other posts and cannot figure out how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arcname parameter will set the exact path within the zip file for the file you are adding.  You issue is when you are building the path for arcname you are using the wrong value to get the length of the prefix to remove.  Specifically:

```
arcname=os.path.join(folder[len(os.path.dirname(folder)) + 1:], file)
```

Should be changed to:

```
arcname=os.path.join(folder[len(src):], file)
```